# How to join my tables?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, join, select-query

I'm using a Sqlite3 database and I have 3 tables which I want to join. My program basically has documents. And you can select multiple employees that belong to the document. But employees can also belong to other documents.

**Below are my tables:**

*Table Employee:*

- id:Integer primary key

*Table Document:*

- id:Integer primary key

*Table DocEmp:*

- id:Integer primary key
- docId:Integer
- empId:Integer
- state:Integer

The DocEmp table can be empty only the Employee and Document table is always filled. **Most important is that i always want to load all employees!**

**So for example:**
I have 3 employees with id's: 1,2 and 3. Have 2 documents with id 1 and 2.
The DocEmp has the following records:
Row1: 1,1,1,0
Row2: 2,1,2,1
So this means only document 1 has 2 employees with id 1 and 2. So when i'm in document 1 i want to load all 3 employees, and also want to know the state of the 2 employees that are filled in for that document in the DocEmp table. And because document 2 has no employees i need just all the employees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you might be looking for a `left join`:

```
select e.id as employeeid,
       d.id as documentid,
       de.state as state     
from employee e
--this could be an inner join but your example is confusing
left join document d on e.id = d.id 
left join docemp de on e.id = de.empid 
                   and d.id = de.docid;
```